# Pointless groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, finite-fields

This question now has two sequels, [Pointless groups II](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii) (to which @R.vanDobbendeBruyn gave a [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091038_424456) for an infinite, imperfect field) and [Pointless groups III](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424489/pointless-groups-iii), both using revised wording suggested by [@DanielLitt](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424444/pointless-groups#comment1091016_424453).

Fix a field $k$—not algebraically closed, and, in fact, this question is obviously of interest only if $k$ is finite.  (EDIT:  @R.vanDobbendeBruyn pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091035_424456) to [Pointless groups II](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii) that my memory that the $k$-points are Zariski-dense in the infinite case is only guaranteed true for reductive groups.)  Then "group" means "smooth, connected, affine algebraic group scheme of finite type over $k$".

Is it possible to have a (smooth, connected) group $G$, and a proper (smooth, connected) subgroup $H$, such that $G(k) = H(k)$?  If so, then can this even happen for $H$ the trivial subgroup?

I have a small store of counterexamples showing that certain naïve statements about rational points of algebraic groups can fail for small fields $k$.  (For example: $C_G(S)(k) \ne C_G(S(k))$ for $S$ a maximal torus in $\operatorname{SL}_2$ when $k$ has $2$ elements.)  None of them provides an example of this sort of behaviour, but, then again, it is a very small testbed.  If this question is too elementary for MO, then I have no objection to migrating it to MSE.

Comment: For future reference: more discussion at the follow-up [Pointless groups II](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424456/).

Comment: And a 2nd sequel, with @R.vanDobbendeBruyn's help and suggestions, at [Pointless groups III](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424489/pointless-groups-iii).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that $k=\mathbb{F}_2$, $G=\mathbb{G}_{m, k}$ works, where $H$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Ha!  Well, that's embarrassing.  My small collection of counterexamples should obviously be made bigger by including smaller groups.

Comment: @LSpice: I am curious if there are examples other than split tori over $\mathbb{F}_2$, with $H$ trivial (one can make lots of examples with $H$ non-trivial by taking products with this example).

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424444/pointless-groups/424453#comment1091016_424453)'s a good generalisation, that might well cover (in the sense of ruling out this sort of bad behaviour) the situation I have in mind.  Do you think that that might be worth asking as a separate question?  If so, then of course you would be welcome to ask it yourself, or I can if you prefer not to do so.

Comment: @LSpice you should feel free to ask it! I think it’s plausible these are the only examples and I have some idea for an argument, but there are some details to check.

Comment: [Done](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii).  [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424444/pointless-groups/424453#comment1091019_424453)!