# Pointless groups II

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

This question is a sequel to [Pointless groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424444/pointless-groups), where I asked for a certain kind of counterexample.  @DanielLitt [produced](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424453) an elegant and easy-to-understand counterexample, but also [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424444/pointless-groups#comment1091016_424453) a sense in which it might be the only counterexample.

At the suggestion of [@R.vanDobbendeBruyn](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091038_424456) and [@YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091103_424456), this question has yet another sequel: [Pointless groups III](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424489/pointless-groups-iii).

Fix a field $k$ — not algebraically closed, and, in fact, this question is obviously of interest only if $k$ is finite.  (EDIT:  @R.vanDobbendeBruyn points out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091035_424456) that my memory that the $k$-points are Zariski-dense in the infinite case is only guaranteed true for reductive groups, and gives a [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091038_424456) for an infinite, imperfect field.)  Then "group" means "smooth, connected, affine algebraic group scheme of finite type over $k$".

If $G$ is a (smooth, connected) group, and $G(k)$ is trivial, then does that imply that $k = \mathbb F_2$ and $G$ is a split torus?

Comment: Why is this only of interest for $k$ finite? Elliptic curves can have trivial group of $k$-points over infinite fields (e.g. number fields). There is a result that $G$ is unirational (hence $G(k) \subseteq G$ is dense) if $G$ is a smooth, connected, affine algebraic group over $k$ and either $G$ is reductive or $k$ is perfect, but this is far from obvious. What about the remaining cases (e.g. pseudoreductive groups over imperfect fields)?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091035_424456), as specified, I am only considering affine algebraic groups, although I would certainly be interested in any interesting comments you have about the non-affine case.  In the smooth, connected, affine algebraic case, $G(k)$ is dense in $G$ once $k$ is infinite (isn't it?  I always get these hypotheses mixed up.  At least it is so when $k$ is separably closed, even if imperfect).

Comment: Ah, in fact Conrad–Gabber–Prasad construct a smooth connected $1$-dimensional pseudo-reductive group $G$ over $k = \mathbf F_p(t)$ for $p > 2$ with $G(k) = 0$; see *Pseudo-reductive groups*, Example 11.3.2. But all is well when you add "perfect" as assumption ― of course the question over finite fields is still interesting!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091038_424456)!  Would you post that as an answer?  And indeed I see that the result I was [remembering](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091036_424456) that only required $k$ to be infinite was for $G$ reductive (although the result about density of $G(k)$ for $k$ separably closed is true even without that assumption).  I am reluctant to change the question once more to *require* $k$ finite.

Comment: Indeed I'd like to see the case $k$ finite in another question (the case of $k$ not perfect doesn't sound surprising to me).

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424456/pointless-groups-ii#comment1091103_424456), [done](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424489/pointless-groups-iii).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One other type of example is constructed in Conrad–Gabber–Prasad's *Pseudo-reductive groups*, Example 11.3.2. The construction is kind of classic (and possibly predates the book), so let me recall it here:

**Example.** Let $k = \bar{\mathbf F}_p(t)$, and let $G \subseteq \mathbf G_a \times \mathbf G_a$ be the subgroup
$$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbf G_a \times \mathbf G_a\ \big|\ y^p = x-tx^p\right\}.$$
It is smooth and becomes isomorphic to $\mathbf G_a$ over $k(t^{1/p})$ (replace $y$ by $y+t^{1/p}x$ and eliminate $x$).

**Lemma.** *If $p > 2$, then $G(k) = \{(0,0)\}$.*

*Proof.* Let $(x,y) \in G(k)$. If $x = 0$, then $y = 0$ as well, so we may assume $x \neq 0$. Then $x$ cannot be a $p$-th power, for otherwise $t$ is a $p$-th power. Thus there exists $a \in \bar{\mathbf F}_p$ such that $v:=v_a(x)$ is not divisible by $p$. The equation $y^p = x-tx^p$ gives
$$(y+ax)^p = x-(t-a)x^p.$$
The ultrametric triangle inequality implies that if $\alpha+\beta = \gamma$, then the set of valuations $\{v_a(\alpha),v_a(\beta),v_a(\gamma)\} \subseteq \mathbf Z \cup \{\infty\}$ has at most $2$ elements.
Since $v_a((y+ax)^p)$ is divisible by $p$ but neither $v=v_a(x)$ nor $v_a((t-a)x^p)=pv+1$ is, we conclude that $v=pv+1$, i.e. $(p-1)v=-1$, which is impossible since $p > 2$ and $v \in \mathbf Z$. $\square$

For $p = 2$ there is also the point $(1/t,0)$, and again Conrad–Gabber–Prasad show that this is the only other point.

**Remark.** On the other hand, if $k$ is an infinite field and either $k$ is perfect or $G$ is reductive, then $G$ is unirational, hence $G(k) \subseteq G$ dense. See for instance [Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf), Corollaries 19.21 and 19.22. Thus, the only examples are among imperfect fields and finite fields.

Comment: The last fact ($G(k)$ Zariski-dense) is due to Rosenlicht.

Comment: It's surprising to me to see one case where $p = 2$ *isn't* the worst-behaved prime!

Comment: @LSpice maybe it secretly is ― I expect the same argument works if you replace by $tx^p$ by $tx^q$ for a power $q > 2$ of $p$ (e.g. $q=4$).